# How to remove selected existing data and add new row without affecting other rows in Jquery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I have 100 rows of data, i want to remove selected data based on ID and add new row for that ID. I want to edit the rows based on ID.
Here is my code:

```
oCustomization : {
            sExportFunctionCall : oMapUrls.exportLiveFleetReport,
            bAdvanceExport : true,
            bShowDefaultAll : !bLivePaginate
        },
        pageLength : !bLivePaginate ? -1 : Global.rowLength,
        scrollCollapse : false,
        scrollY : iDataTableHeight,
        serverSide : bLivePaginate,
        order : [ [ 3, "desc" ] ],
        columns : [
                {
                    "data" : "trackeeName",
                    "width" : aColumnWidths[0],
                    "class" : "no-word-break",
                    "settings" : {
                        source : function(request, oCallback) {
                            oCallback($.ui.autocomplete.filter(Global.aJSTreeVehicleItems || [], request.term));
                        }
                    },

                    "render" : function(value, type, rowData) {
                      //Some code here

                    }
                },
                {
                    "data" : "firstName",
                    "width" : aColumnWidths[1],
                    "class" : "no-word-break",
                    settings : {
                        source : Global.getDriverSuggestion
                    },
                    "title" : jQuery.i18n.prop("driver.title.txtInfo"),
                    "visible" : Global['show.driver.in.reports'] == 1,
                    "render" : function(value, type, rowData) {
                        return getUserName(rowData.firstName, rowData.lastName);
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data" : "groupName",
                    "width" : aColumnWidths[2],
                    "class" : "no-word-break",
                    "settings" : {
                        source : function(request, oCallback) {
                           oCallback($.ui.autocomplete.filter(Global.aJSTreeGroupItems || [], request.term));
                        }
                    },
                    "title" : jQuery.i18n.prop("vehicle.col2label")
                },
                {
                    "data" : "dateAndTime",
                    "width" : aColumnWidths[3],
                    "searchable" : !bLivePaginate,
                    "class" : "wordBreak",
                    "title" : jQuery.i18n.prop("report.columnTitle.date"),
                    "render" : function(value, type, rowData) {
                        if (type == "display") {
                            return rowData.formattedDate;
                        }
                        return value;
                    }
                }
```

I get data in JSON format. I want to remove selected rows , it should not affect other rows data.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I Have posted my code @JohnR

Answer (score 1):

Simply use WHERE

DELETE FROM DBNAME WHERE ID=XXX

then Insert into the table with that ID

however, if you want to delete and insert together always, an UPDATE query will work better

Comment: Sorry missed to mention table. I want to delete it on webtable